# Is there an elementary HIG-compliant screenshot app?

Tags: applications, screenshot, software-recommendation

Shutter is nice, but it's not an elementary-styled app, and it's a bit hefty at times.

Is there an alternative for quick screen-shots?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default one is gnome-screenshot and as far as I can tell it respects the HIG guidelines (see window decorations).

[image]

Looking through 3rd-party solutions specifically developed for elementary OS, there's [a similar tool](http://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Screenshot/) which makes use of a dark theme.

[image]

There is also a [request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1415120) to pull it in as the new default screenshot tool in the next release of elementary OS.